# Probability of placing $k$ balls in $n$ bins?

Tags: probability

We have $n$ bins and $k$ balls, with $1 \leq k \leq n$.
The balls are placed in the bins, knowing that the placement of each ball is independent of the others, and that the bins are chosen in an equiprobable way.

1. Calculate the probability that each bin contains at most one ball.
2. Calculate the probability that a bin contains all balls.
3. Calculate the probability that a bin contains at least two balls.

My attempt:

1. The probability that each bin contains at most one ball is the probability that a bin contains at most one ball $n$ times. Now, the probability that a bin contains at most one ball is the probability that it contains exactly one ball plus the probability that it contains no balls.

I think that the probability that it contains exactly one ball is $k/n$.

I cannot continue. Any helps? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that your fomulation is correct? If k<n then the probablity #1 is 0 as there in this case at least one bin must remain empty.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze At most, not at least.

Comment: @Clement C. thank you, sorry, my error. Next attempt: prob(3) = 1 - prob(1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have 1., you can immediately get 3.: these are complementary events.

To answer 1., observe that for this even to happen, you first need to place the first ball into any bin; then the second into any of the remaining $n-1$ bins; then the third into any of the remaining $n-2$ bins; etc. So your probability is
$$
\mathbb{P}\{\text{no collision}\} = 1\cdot\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{n-2}{n}\cdots\cdot\frac{n-(k-1)}{n} = \prod_{\ell=0}^{k-1} \frac{n-\ell}{n} = \frac{n!}{n^k (n-k)!}
$$
Sanity check: for $k=1$, you get $1$.

Now, to answer 2. Your event corresponds to the union of $n$ disjoint events (namely: "all balls in bin #1", "all bins in bin #2", ..., "all balls in bin #n"). The probability of each of these events is exactly
$$
\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^k = \frac{1}{n^k}
$$
since the $k$ balls are placed independently. So the overall probability is $n\cdot \frac{1}{n^k} = \frac{1}{n^{k-1}}$. (again, for $k=1$, you do get $1$, as expected).

Comment: Why is it wrong to calculate 3. as follows: we have ${k \choose 2}$ ways to choose two balls out of the $k$-many which must be in the same bin. There are $n$-many bins, hence ${k \choose 2}*n$ many ways for two balls to be placed in the same bin. The $k-2$ remaining balls can be placed in any bin. So the probability of at least $2$ balls in any bin is $\frac{{k \choose 2}*n* n^{k-2}}{n^k}$.

Comment: Ouh I think I know where my mistake is. I am overcounting e.g. the tuple $(1,1,2,2,3,3,.....)$ will be counted $n$ times instead of one time. Can someone please confirm this?

Comment: @Philipp That looks like the issue, yes. From what I gather: say you pick the first two balls to be $1,2$, to fall in bin 1. Then $3,4$ can also fall in bin #1. Or you pick the first two balls to be $3,4$ to fall in bin #1. Then $1,2$ can also fall in bin #1. Your approach would count these two as different.

Comment: hmm, I very often run into those overcounting mistakes :S. I think I need to practice more.